# How does opensea create token Id for the opensea collection contract

Tags: opensea

I understand that the tokenId of the opensea collection contract is not randomly and it is encoding of different data . Can someone help me to find which all data opensea uses to create that tokenid

Comment: OpenSea doesn't create token id because it doesn't create tokens in the first place. It is an exchange only so all tokens must previously exist before exchanging. So you need to contract the developer if you want to find out about token id assembly, most likely it is just sequentially generated

Comment: Opensea allows you to create nft on the platform . They use a erc-1155 standard .